# How to make windows freeze for short period of time

Tags: windows, windows-7, driver, windows-7-embedded, filter-driver

Can I make windows 7 freeze for a short period of time, 
during this time I want it to perform absolutely no action. 
In particular, the OS should not access to any storage device.

My original idea was to crate an interrupt, however, I think that long interrupt will cause a blue screen (which I want to prevent).

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes, I want to stop all pending I/O operations. I still don't know how to "Pause" the system, therefore, I don't know how to "Unpause"

Comment: Michael: During the frozen time, I want to the power of HDD off (secondary HDD, not the OS HDD).

Comment: Why do you need to freeze the system for that?

Comment: Well, my OS drive is connected on the same bus as the secondary HDD, when I power off the HDD, the OS disk is getting disconnected for a very short time. sometimes, during this period, if the system is performing some kind of action, it freezes, without any option to recover (hard system reboot is required).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can tell you for a fact that this is not possible - if you do this to the primary volume the machine will bluescreen because of a watchdog timer, even for a short time. If you disconnect the drive, it will immediately bluescreen. If you do this to a secondary volume, it will be surprise removed.

If you have less than a team of 10-20 **very** skilled NT kernel developers / testers, this idea is not even beginning to be practical. What is your scenario and what you're trying to accomplish at a high level?

Comment: During the frozen time, I want to the power of HDD off (secondary HDD, not the OS HDD).

Comment: my OS drive is connected on the same bus as the secondary HDD, when I power off the HDD, the OS disk is getting disconnected for a very short time. sometimes, during this period, if the system is performing some kind of action, it freezes, without any option to recover (hard system reboot is required).

Comment: I know. And I'm telling you, that this is *not reasonably possible*.